# Need Active Admin to redirect to the login page when following the download CSV link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, devise, activeadmin

I'm working on a cron task that e-mails out a link to download a CSV file from Active Admin. The link looks like something along the lines of:
`www.adminsite.com/admin/records.csv`

If the user isn't already authenticated into the system -- active admin redirects to the page that just says "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." instead of redirecting to the login page and then following through with a CSV download link upon successful authentication.

I've tried looking into active admin internals, but have not been able to figure it out yet. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**!!! EDIT !!!**

I actually ended up solving this issue on my own.

Because the link I was generating was navigating to a csv format, I had to add in the :csv option as a navigational format to **devise.rb** configuration file:

```
config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html, :csv]
```

Now the redirect to the login page was working, but it was taking the user to /admin/login.csv, which was coming back as an empty page. I'm assuming there was no template for a csv format.

I had to set up the redirect from /admin/login.csv to /admin/login by adding this to the **routes.rb** file:

```
 devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config do
    match "/admin/login.csv" => redirect("/admin/login")
  end
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Active Admin uses devise to handle its logins, which is probably why you couldn't find anything.

From the instructions [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated):

Create this class in lib/custom_failure.rb:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    #return super unless [:worker, :employer, :user].include?(scope) #make it specific to a scope
     new_user_session_url(:subdomain => 'secure')
  end

  # You need to override respond to eliminate recall
  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end
end
```

And add this to config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
end
```

Comment: Not sure if that would accomplish what I was trying to do, but I solved the issue myself and posted the solution in my question.